# apache RewriteRule configuration

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a domain mail.domain.com/webaccess

I'm able to enforce https using the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://mail.domain.com/webaccess/ [R]
```

how can I remove the alias /webaccess , so users don't have to type long url and how can I remove www if user typed it.

Note: /webaccess alias actually points to /opt/mailserver in my file system.

Thank you

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf] or maybe [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 0):

For the www part, you can add something similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For the first option, if the user types in mail.domain.com, you want them to directly go to https://mail.domain.com/webaccess?

If so, you can do everything by the following ruleL

```
RedirectPermanent / https://mail.domain.com/webaccess
```